# Stop training caffe from c++ code in qt

Tags: c++, qt, neural-network, caffe

I want to stop training in `caffe`. I Know that there is a signal by the name of `SIGINT` that is emitted when I press `ctrl+c` in the console and after that training will be stopped.

Now I use `caffe` from c++ codes in qt and I want to emit `SIGINT` signal by pressing a button. So how can I do that?

Comment: man pages of signal.h

Comment: thanks Aram, but if I `emit SIGINT;` how can I stop training? (What should I connect to this signal?)

Comment: You should be looking at caffe's source code.. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/536851c00e44d545649648b372503f52a89c0499/include/caffe/solver.hpp